# Any possibility of instantiating sub work flow from an executing work flow

Tags: workflow

Can anybody suggest if there is a way to instantiate a sub work flow from a work flow in SDL web 8?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of "sub-workflow"...

I've done work (in 2011 even) where a given workflow step would trigger another workflow for the same item in a child publication, and this was totally fine via the API.

Can you expand on your requirement?